# 18.10 won't bring up desktop; can ssh into it and run lightdm

Tags: boot, upgrade, do-release-upgrade, 18.10

I upgraded to 18.10 from 18.04 using `do-release-upgrade`. The upgrade was successful, but on rebooting, the system seems to freeze after the Plymouth splash screen and systemd (OK/FAIL) status output, but before the desktop. I don't get a tty login either. This happens with both the 4.18.0-10-generic and 4.15.0-10-generic kernels.

Updates:

Using another PC, I can `ssh` into the host and then run `sudo lightdm` to bring up the desktop.

Changing grub options from `quiet splash` to `nomodeset` did not fix the problem.

Renaming `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to `xorg.conf.bak` did not fix the problem.

Comment: I was able to fix all my issues. I am running it on Dell XPS 15 9570. What is your hardware? I posted my issues (and temporary the fix) here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/9puckt/ubuntu_1810_on_dell_xps_15_9570/